# Переключение класса при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такая структура:

```
<div class="trading__nav-active" >
  <nav>
    <input class="RadioTab" name="odin" type="radio" id="CoinVal_1" checked="checked" onclick = 'CoinValChange("CoinVal_1");'/>
    <label for="CoinVal_1" >1</label>                                                                                       

    <input class="RadioTab" name="odin" type="radio" id="CoinVal_2" onclick = 'CoinValChange("CoinVal_2");'/>
    <label for="CoinVal_2">2</label>    
  </nav>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы каждый раз при клике на label, текущий элемент подсвечивался или выделялся цветом, а предыдущий возвращался в исходное состояние?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут просто напрашивается CSS...

```css
/* .RadioTab {display: none;} */

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.RadioTab:checked + label {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="trading__nav-active">
  <nav>
    <input class="RadioTab" name="odin" type="radio" id="CoinVal_1" checked="checked">
    <label for="CoinVal_1">1</label>
    
    <input class="RadioTab" name="odin" type="radio" id="CoinVal_2">
    <label for="CoinVal_2">2</label>
  </nav>
</div>
```

А на JS можно записать так, уже независимо от радиокнопок:

```js
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.test'); // Возвращает список элементов
let lastClicked = test[0]; // Первый элемент из списка (счет начинается с нуля)

for( let i = 0; i < test.length; i++ ){
  // Цикл берет и кругами выполняет код. На каждом круге, i является конкретным числом.
  // Добавляется событие 'клик' на test[0], потом test[1], test[2]...
  test[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    lastClicked.classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
    // Убрали класс с предыдущего кликнутого элемента, добавили на текущий
    
    lastClicked = this; 
    // Обновили значение переменной - теперь она ссылается на текущий элемент. 
    // Чтобы на следующем клике, убрать класс уже с этого.
  });
}
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<label class="test">1</label>
<label class="test">2</label>
<label class="test">3</label>
<label class="test">4</label>
<label class="test">5</label>
```

Учебник JS → http://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Спасибо большое!