# Как удалить класс у DOM элемента при повторном нажатии?

Tags: javascript

Как при повторном нажатии убрать добавленный клас?

```
document.querySelector('.menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('nav').classList.add('active');
})
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Переключение класса при клике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044664/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 3):

Удалять класс надо с помощью `classList.remove(className)`. Но мне кажется вам нужен переключатель с помощью `classList.toggle(className)`:

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

div.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>Click me</p>
```